# Why does each overlay mount in Docker say that it is the full size of the root filesystem?

Tags: docker, storage

Dumb question, but I'm a bit confused. When I run df -h, I get the following output:

[image]

Why does each mount corresponding to a Docker container running say that it is 26GB? Does this mean that all of the containers have access to the full 26GB of the root filesystem? I was hoping to be able to limit the size that the containers could use so that the root filesystem doesn't run out of space in the event that the container uses up all of the storage capacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what Overlay is about -- to enable the container to access the host's whole file system.

If you want to impose a limit on the container, you should mount a *disk* volume (something other than the disk volume holding the root filesystem) at some convenient place in the server root filesystem, then define the *container* volumes to paths under that mountpoint.